# Is there a way to add a foreign key to a table?

Tags: 7, database

My question is not regarding `hook_schema` but regarding `hook_update_N`: I need to add a foreign key to an existent table in drupal 7.

I was looking [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/150223) but it does not seem to exist one explicitly for foreign keys.

**Q**: How can I create a foreign key in an existent table? Which call should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying DBMS all support this, but Drupal7 Core doesn't really care about Foreign Keys (FKs). Views will notice them and use them abit within joins.

Drupal 7 only supports FK in documentation:
http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jkhalaj/2012/04/12/drupal-7-usage-foreign-keys-schema-api-and-current-default-fk-erd

But, if you know this and understand this, then you can still use this `foreign key` defintion to create the FKs in a module.install file specific to your DBMS.

I use MySQL typically -- and I have done this for a foreign database my settings.php is aware of within a module.install file:

```
function _idremotedb_add_foreign_keys() {
  $schema = _idremotedb_schema_definition();
  db_set_active('sa_webextracts');
  foreach ($schema as $table => $table_schema) {
    if (isset($table_schema['foreign keys'])) {
      foreach ($table_schema['foreign keys'] as $fk_name => $fk_details) {
        $src_col = $fk_details['columns'][0];
        $dest_col = $fk_details['columns'][1];
        $dest_table = $fk_details['table'];
        // Create the FK using your DBMS convention. Change this as necessary
        // or add a lookup to the database handler driver type (mysql, postgres, whatever) ...
        db_query("
          ALTER TABLE $table ADD CONSTRAINT $fk_name
          FOREIGN KEY ($src_col) REFERENCES $dest_table($dest_col);
        ");
        drupal_set_message(t('...added foreign key: !fk', array('!fk' => $fk_name)));
      }
    }
  }
  // This index added for either mail-list or login.
  #db_add_index('students', 'uniqueidnumber', 'campusuniqueidnumber');
  db_set_active();
}
```

Comment: Seems you're right, and learned that it also does not exist in the schema core, being like a big "TO-DO". Drupal sucks - and I'm forced to use it. The (part I used from the) code you gave me works :).

Comment: @LuisMasuelli No problem. I hope it works -- it's live on a site i have :). And it looks like D8 will have some support for creating FKs **in contrib modules** but not used explicitly in Core: https://www.drupal.org/node/2254131